# How to Use rename() Within Array Of File Names

Tags: php

PHP `rename()` function renames a file like

```
rename(oldname,newname)
```

but in my case I need to rename bulk files based on two arrays `$activeNames` which are current names to `$fakeNames` array which are new names. can you please let me know how to do this?

```
<?php
$dir = "data/";
$activeNames = ["map.php","tap.php","app.php"];
$fakeNames =["fake1.php","fake2.php","fake3.php"];
if(file_exists($dir."map.php")){
    rename($dir."map.php", $dir."noha.php");
}
   else {echo "File Name Already Changed";}
```

Comment: `foreach($activeNames as $key => $fromFilename) { $toFilename = $fakeNames[$key]; rename($fromFilename, $toFilename); }`

Comment: Thanks Mark but I am getting this error `Warning: rename(map.php,fake1.php): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\wamp\www\Rename\index.php on line 6
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location`

Comment: You'll have to add your directory to the renames..... all I did was demonstrate how to iterate over the array and get the from/to filenames from it.... I assumed you'd be able to figure out something as basic as that yourself. `foreach($activeNames as $key => $fromFilename) { $toFilename = $fakeNames[$key]; rename($dir . $fromFilename, $dir . $toFilename); }`

Comment: This is working perfectly but I really need to understand the way you used the associated array here! specifically the `$key => $fromFilename` !

Comment: It's not an associative array, it's an enumerated array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dir = "data/";
$activeNames = ["map.php","tap.php","app.php"];
$fakeNames =["fake1.php","fake2.php","fake3.php"];
```

creates 2 arrays, both of which have default keys set for each element.... effectively it's

```
$activeNames = [0 => "map.php",   1 => "tap.php",   2 => "app.php"];
$fakeNames   = [0 => "fake1.php", 1 => "fake2.php", 2 => "fake3.php"];
```

Then the loop:

```
foreach($activeNames as $key => $fromFilename) {
    $toFilename = $fakeNames[$key];
    rename($dir . $fromFilename, $dir . $toFilename);
}
```

First iteration gets the first key and value from `$activeNames` as `$key` and `$fromFilename` respectively, so `$key` is `0` and `$fromFilename` is `map.php` and then gets the element from `$fakeNames` with key `0` ($key), which is `fake1.php`. Does the rename, and loops.

Second iteration gets the second key and value from `$activeNames` as `$key` and `$fromFilename` respectively, so `$key` is `1` and `$fromFilename` is `tap.php` and then gets the element from `$fakeNames` with key `1` ($key), which is `fake2.php`. Does the rename, and loops.

Third iteration gets the third key and value from `$activeNames` as `$key` and `$fromFilename` respectively, so `$key` is `2` and `$fromFilename` is `app.php` and then gets the element from `$fakeNames` with key `2` ($key), which is `fake3.php`. Does the rename, and terminates the loop because it's the last entry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dir = "data/";
$activeNames = ["map.php","tap.php","app.php"];
$fakeNames =["fake1.php","fake2.php","fake3.php"];
$errors = "";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($activeNames);$i++){
    if(file_exists($dir.$activeNames[$i])){
            rename($dir.$activeNames[$i], $dir.$fakeNames[$i]);
    }
       else {$error.="File Name Already Changed\n";}

}
echo $errors;
```

Comment: thanks thepiyush13 there is only one thing on echoing the error message because it is inside the loop! is there any way to check file existence before the loop?

Comment: I think you DO want to check the existence before renaming the file, as for error message , please see my updated answer

Comment: well it is poping up a error message on page like `Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\wamp\www\Rename\index.php on line 10
Call Stack`

Comment: I fixed it but still getting three times(as size of the array length error message

Comment: oh my bad there was a typo, $error should be $errors, you are getting three error message because there are 3 files to be checked , if you do not need it you can remove error messages, also pls make sure the files exist

Comment: Yeah thanks, but its kinda annoying! I wish there would a better way to check all files in once instead of doing one by one!